# Create a product list, each with quantity and 'add to cart' button

Tags: php

I am working on an unstyled page that uses PHP to create a basic shopping cart. However, the page is built using a dropdown, which is difficult & inefficient to use because of the amount of products.

I'd like to change it so each item has its own quantity & add to cart button. Unfortunately, all the different configurations I have tried always give me the same error - Column 'product_id' cannot be null. I have been able to get it to stop giving me this error, but it also will not pass along the price & product name.

Here's the original code (just the portion that creates the section I'm trying to change; let me know if you need more):

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post">
   <p><label for="product_name">Product Name:</label><br />
   <select name="product_name">
      <?php
          do {  
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row_getProducts['product_id']?>">
      <?php echo $row_getProducts['store_name']?></option>
      <?php
          } while ( $row_getProducts = mysql_fetch_assoc( $getProducts ) );
              $rows = mysql_num_rows( $getProducts );
              if ( $rows > 0 ) {
                 mysql_data_seek( $getProducts, 0 );
             $row_getProducts = mysql_fetch_assoc( $getProducts );
              }
      ?>
      </select></p>
      <p><label for="quantityt">Quantity:</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="quantity" value="" /></p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Item to Cart" />
      <input type="hidden" name="total" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="first_item" />
   </form>
```

This code doesn't return an error, but it only passes the quantity one time:

```
<p><label for="product_name">Product Name:</label><br /><br />

  <?php
    do {  
  ?>
  <input name="check1" type="checkbox" /> <?php echo $row_getProducts['product_id']?> <?php echo $row_getProducts['store_name']?> 1 <?php echo $row_getProducts['price']?> <br />

  <p><label for="quantityt">Quantity:</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="" /></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Item to Cart" />
  <input type="hidden" name="total" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="first_item2" />

<br />

  <?php
  } while ( $row_getProducts = mysql_fetch_assoc( $getProducts ) );
      $rows = mysql_num_rows( $getProducts );
      if ( $rows > 0 ) {
          mysql_data_seek( $getProducts, 0 );
          $row_getProducts = mysql_fetch_assoc( $getProducts );
      }
  ?>
</p>
</form>
```

Any thoughts you can pass along would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

j.

Comment: How do you mean, instead of a dropdown you just want a list or something?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? When saving to the database? If so, then provide the code to get the input and save the data.

Comment: @marijke yes, just a list with checkboxes next to each item, a quantity box, and the add to cart button. Thanks!

Comment: @crafter i've broken the product list out fo the dropdown, and got it LOOKING the way I want, but when I hit the add to cart button, thats when I get that error. Thank you!

Comment: Probably because you have multiple values coming back with POST instead of 1. You could think of making a form on each product so you get back 1 value, but that's not the most beautifull thing.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the dropdown to something like this:

```
<input type='text' name="<?php echo $row_getProducts['product_id'] ?>" value="<?php $row_getProducts['store_name'] ?>">
```

And add the quantity buttons behind it along with the product_id.

Comment: thanks so much for you help, @marijke. I added some code to my original post that doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't go to the cart correctly. It doesn't pass along the price or name to the cart, just the quantity, and it only works once - if I try to add another item, it replaces it.